# How to display tuple items inside template

Tags: django

I want to use items from a tuple I'm currently using in my models.py inside my template. I added this tuple to my views' context but when I try to loop over it nothing shows up.
this is my simplified view:

```
def dashboard(request):
    documents = DocumentInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'documents':documents}
    if request.user.role == 'theory_interviewer':
        template = loader.get_template('reg/scientific-info-dashboard.html')
        interviewed = ScientificInfo.objects.filter(is_interviewed=True).all()
        context['interviewed'] = len(interviewed)
        context['survey_choices'] = SURVEY_CHOICES
    
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request, context=context))
```

and this is my template:

```
{% for x,y in survey_choices %}
    {{x}}{{y}}
{% endfor %}
```

and finally, this is the choice tuple I imported from models.py:

```
SURVEY_CHOICES = (
    ('0', 'very bad'),
    ('1', 'bad'),
    ('2', 'good'),
    ('3', 'very good'),
    ('4', 'nice')
)
```

Comment: You're passing your ``context['survey_choices']`` inside this condition ``if request.user.role == 'theory_interviewer':`` so if this condition is **False** your data will not rendered

Comment: But why does the interviewed context work just fine?

Comment: Try to print **SURVEY_CHOICES** inside if condition check what it gives as output